# Accessing properties of the base class in a double derived class

Tags: c#, properties, radix, derived

I am having trouble accessing the properties of the baseclass in a double derived class. I have included a simple example of my problem below.

```
public class Device
{
   public Device(string status)
   {
      Status = status;
   }

   public string Status { get; set; }

   public void SetStatus(string value)
   {
      Status = value;
   }

   public string GetStatus()
   {
      return Status;
   }
}

public class Light : Device
{
   public Light(string status) : base(status)
   {
   }

   public void SetStatus(string value)
   {
      base.SetStatus(value)
   }

   public string GetStatus()
   {
      return Status;
   }
}

public class ColoredLight : Light
{
   public ColoredLight(string status) : base(status)
   {
   }

   public void SetStatus(string value)
   {
      base.SetStatus(value)
   }

   public string GetStatus()
   {
      return Status;
   }
}

// note: The derived classes also have some properties of their own, of course, 
// but they are not needed to illustrate the problem
```

I know the Status property of the baseclass definitely gets set to a value, but if I call the GetStatus method in the ColoredLight class it returns null.

If I change the GetStatus functions in the Light and ColoredLight class to return base.GetStatus() it does return the correct value. However, I thought that it should be possible to access the properties of the baseclass directly in the derived classes. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just how it should be done?

Thanks in advance for the help.

edit: [Solved] The problem I was having was due to stupidity and an oversight by myself, as I declared the Status property in both the Device and Light class. However, the solutions below have improved my understanding of the use of 'protected', 'virtual' and 'override' in C#, so I will leave the question as is, so it can maybe help others as well!

Comment: Aren't you getting warnings with that code since you aren't overriding the SetStatus and GetStatus methods?

Comment: You programed in java before, didnt you? Its not the problem but OOP usually written a little different in C#. (no explicitly named Get and Set)

Comment: I actually am getting a warning from Resharper that I should use the new keyword, but the code builds and the correct method gets called, so I didn't think that causes the problem here. Although you are right in that I will have to change that as well.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the help. But as I mentioned below I think I have oversimplified the code too much, as my actual methods return property values specific to either the derived class or one of the base classes, depending on the value of a parameter. So the actual methods differ somewhat in the different classes. Furthermore, the methods also do some other work before returning, so I can't just use the publicly accessible property.

What my question basically boils down to is this: why is the value of Status null in the derived class, while it is definitely set in the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the GetStatus() and SetStatus() methods altogether, this is not java. instead make the property `virtual` and override it in the descendant classes as needed.

```
public class Device
{
    public Device(string status)
    {
        this._status = status;
    }

    protected _status;
    public virtual string Status 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Light : Device
{
    public Light(string status) : base(status)
    {
    }
}

public class ColoredLight : Light
{
    public ColoredLight(string status) : base(status)
    {
    }

    public override string Status 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I may have oversimplified the problem. The GetStatus() method is just an example. The actual method I use is a little more complex and depending on the value of a parameter either returns a value specific to the derived class, or a value from one of the baseclasses.

I have now tried it with the methods declared as `virtual` and `override`, but this makes no difference. For some reason I am not able to directly access a property from the baseclass in the derived classes. I can only access them through some `base.GetProperty()` method.

Comment: Ok, I think my exact problem was actually caused by something else entirely. Mainly stupidity on my part, as I accidentally defined Status in both the Device class and the Light class, and didn't see it until I was changing the code to your solution.

The example on `protected`, `virtual` and `override` you provided did help me a lot though with understanding how I can make my code better! So thank you!